# Pyspark applying foreach

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm nooby in Pyspark and I pretend to play a bit with a couple of functions to understand better how could I use them in more realistic scenarios. for a while, I trying to apply a specific function to each number coming in a RDD. My problem is basically that, when I try to print what I grabbed from my RDD the result is None

My code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf , SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sc.setLogLevel("WARN")


changed = []

def div_two (n):
    opera = n / 2
    return opera

numbers = [8,40,20,30,60,90]

numbersRDD = sc.parallelize(numbers)

changed.append(numbersRDD.foreach(lambda x: div_two(x)))

#result = numbersRDD.map(lambda x: div_two(x))

for i in changed:
    print(i)
```

I appreciate a clear explanation about why this is coming Null in the list and what should be the right approach to achieve that using foreach whether it's possible.

thanks

Comment: Because `foreach` on RDD returns Unit.

Comment: Sorry @Psidom could you elaborate a bit more your answer I appreciate thanks

Comment: Take a look at `numbersRDD.foreach(lambda x: div_two(x))`. Is it NoneType? Or do you mean `numbersRDD.map(lambda x: div_two(x))`?

Comment: I mean the foreach , I posted as comment the map because I know that map will give me the right result because that return a new transformed RDD

Comment: OK. Yes. `foreach` doesn't work because it doesn't return anything. So what you append to the list is essentially `None`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function definition of `div_two` seems fine which can yet be reduced to

```
def div_two (n):
    return n/2
```

And you have converted the arrays of *integers* to *rdd* which is good too.

**The main issue is that you are trying to add *rdds* to an *array* changed by using `foreach` function**. But if you look at the definition of `foreach`

```
def foreach(self, f) Inferred type: (self: RDD, f: Any) -> None
```

which says that the return type is `None`. And thats what is getting printed.

You don't need an array variable for printing the changed *elements* of an *RDD*. You can simply write a function for printing and call that function in `foreach` function

```
def printing(x):
    print x

numbersRDD.map(div_two).foreach(printing)
```

You should get the results printed.

**You can still add the `rdd` to an `array` variable but `rdds` are distributed collection in itself and `Array` is a *collection* too. So if you add rdd to an array you will have *collection* of *collection* which means you should write two loops**

```
changed.append(numbersRDD.map(div_two))

def printing(x):
    print x

for i in changed:
    i.foreach(printing)
```

**The main difference between your code and mine is that I have used map (which is a transformation) instead of foreach ( which is an action) while adding rdd to changed variable**. And I have use two loops for printing the elements of `rdd`

Comment: This answer may still be valid, but is relatively out of date. It only covers RDDs, which are not common anymore in Pyspark. I am looking for a good example myself for doing this with PySpark/DataFrames, so can't provide an ansewr myself yet. But just a warning to future searchers.

Comment: Echoing @DanCiborowski-MSFT's comment. How would one use `foreach` in pyspark dataframes?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach.html