# Pyspark use customized function to store each row into a self defined object, for example a node object

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, transform, python-object

Is there a way to utilize the map function to store each row of the pyspark dataframe into a self-defined python class object?

[pyspark dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSexE.png)

For example, in the picture above I have a spark dataframe, I want to store every row of id, features, label into a node object (with 3 attributes node_id, node_features, and node_label).  I am wondering if this is feasible in pyspark.  I have tried something like

for row in df.rdd.collect()
do_something (row)

but this can not handle big data and is extremely slow.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to resolve it.  Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` method for your operation. The operation will be parallelized in spark.

Refer [Pyspark applying foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435249/pyspark-applying-foreach) if you need more details.

Comment: It will be even more straight forward if you can provide a sample code example of using the dataframe example i provide above, and use the foreach method to convert each row of a dataframe to a custome node object.  I am quite newbie to handling spark dataframe with objects.